# How to POST a note to an Issue and close this issue

Tags: c#, rest, gitlab, gitlab-api

I found an issue and get it's details with:

GET `https://localhost/api/v4/projects/2779/issues/2`

I can add a new_comment to the issue by:

POST `https://localhost/api/v4/projects/2779/issues/2/notes?body=new_comment`

how to close this issue at once with adding comment?

I've tried only to close without a comment by:

PUT `https://localhost/api/v4/projects/2779/issues/2?state_event=close"`
and it works but I have to use to request first POST to comment and then PUT to close it.

Comment: Good catch. I have edited the answer to add the POST note (comment) on issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `\n/close` to the end of your comment to close the issue with a single API call while adding a comment.

`POST https://localhost/api/v4/projects/2779/issues/2/notes?body=new_comment\n/close`

This works because `/close` is one of the [quick actions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/quick_actions.html).

Comment: ...and how to add assignee? I've tried:

`https://localhost/api/v4/projects/2779/issues/20?assignee_id=240` 
and it's not working. I didn't get any error either

Answer (score 0):

> with adding comment

The [Issue "Closing issues automatically" section](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#closing-issues-automatically) mentions:

> If a commit message or merge request description contains text matching a defined pattern, all issues referenced in the matched text are closed.
> This happens when the commit is pushed to a project’s default branch, or when a commit or merge request is merged into it.
>
> For example, if `Closes #4, #6, Related to #5` is included in a Merge Request description, issues `#4` and `#6` are closed automatically when the MR is merged, but not `#5`.

So "comments" are related to commits or MR (Merge Requests), not comment on the issue itself.

The [Edit issue API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#edit-issue) proposes the following call to close an issue:

```sh
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/4/issues/85?state_event=close"
```

That should be pretty similar to what you have tried, except you need the PAT (Personal Access Token) with the [right scope (api)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#limiting-scopes-of-a-personal-access-token).

As the OP found out, the PUT is effective only after posting a comment on said issue: [Create new issue note](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/notes.html#create-new-issue-note)

```
POST /projects/:id/issues/:issue_iid/notes
```

Comment: Ok but on the other hand I am creating an issue with a title using: 

POST ```https://localhost/api/v4/projects/2779/issues?title=TestIssue```

and i want to add a description to this issue in the same POST. 

If it is not possible, how can I find ID or IID of this new issue. I can't find it in POST response   

ps. I know about private-token header.

Comment: @simoNPL In https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#new-issue, the web-url field seems to be the newly created issue URL.